UDP proxy forwarding for LDPlayer emulator
I'm struggling to understand how to implement UDP port forwarding to my LDplayer emulator. I've followed this guide
Setup TCP and UDP forwarding to Android Emulator
But the process doesn't seem to be the same for me. When I type 'adb devices' to check the device ids, I see emulator-5556 and emulator-5564. I'm assuming these are the ports to use, but if I try connecting with telnet to these ports, it does not connect. From what I understand, LDPlayer uses two ports. So emulator-5556 would also be using port 5557 I believe.
However when I run 'telnet localhost 5557', it does seem to connect to something, but I am met with a blank empty terminal screen. I cannot input any commands and I do not understand what seems to be happening. I can type CTRL + ] to exit the blank screen. After that I am in the Telnet prompt, but there is not a command to run 'redir' to redirect a port.
I am using Windows 11 for reference.
